# Apache 2.4 Define variable from another variable or condition

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to `Define` a variable from the value of what is received originally via nginx `proxy_set_header MYVAR "some_value";`

The variable should then be used in `DocumentRoot`, `Directory` and `Alias`.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=MYVAR:%{HTTP:MYVAR}]
SetEnv MYVAR "%{HTTP:MYVAR}"
Define MYVAR ${MYVAR}
```

This doesn't seem to be possible according the Apache documentation which only gives examples on how to set static values. So I tried this:

```
  <If "%{HTTP:MYVAR} == 'value1'">
    Define MYVAR value1
  </If>

  <If "%{HTTP:MYVAR} == 'value2'">
    Define MYVAR value2
  </If>
```

which doesn't work either. It always just executes the `Define` from the last `<If>`.
If I add

```
  <Else>
    Define MYVAR undefined
  </Else>
```

this will be executed, so perhaps something wrong with my Syntax or that whole logic is not working as I think?

I'm running out of Ideas...

Edit: Is it possibly true that `Define` generally doesn't work within `<If>` ?

Comment: I have the same problem with LoadModule in the IF condition

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define I don't think you can. Defines are preprocessed and set at startup - The value is fixed by whichever directive last defines it at that point (hence it taking the latter value, regardless of the `<If>`) and you can't programmatically change it later on.

Since your example sets an EnvVar in the line before, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1):

To set a variable based on the value of the header received in Apache from Nginx proxy, you should use `mod_setenvif` module and its [SetEnvIfNoCase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifnocase) option like this:

where `CF_COUNTRY_CODE` is the variable and its value is set to the value of `CF-IPCountry` header

```
SetEnvIfNoCase CF-IPCountry "(.*)" CF_COUNTRY_CODE=$1
```

and then you can use `CF_COUNTRY_CODE` variable in the directory path

Comment: The problem is that Apache seems to ignore the condition - Both LoadModule commands are executed: <If "'a' == 'b'">LoadModule some_module1 "..."</If><Else>LoadModule some_module2 "..."</Else>

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that whenever I have a module which is not defined, I receive a syntax error at startup, even if the `<IF>` condition does not match.
Obviously the syntax check does not let the setup pass at this point.

The solution for me was use `<IFDefine>`

Wrong:

```
<If "${VAR}=='a'">
    LoadModule module1 "path_to_module1"
</If>
<Else>
    LoadModule module2 "path_to_module2"
</Else>
```

Correct:

```
Define "FFF${VAR}"
<IfDefine FFFa>
    LoadModule module1 "path_to_module1"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !FFFa>
    LoadModule module2 "path_to_module2"
</IfDefine>
```